# Show alert when form submitted

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms

İ have a form. When user click submit button, i want to show alert and submit the form.

Here is my code sample.

```
<form action="DoMakeApplication" Method="post">                             
            <td>
            <button class="btn type7 color1" type="submit" id="makeApplication" onclick="makeApp();return false"  >Başvur</button>
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.companyName}" name="companyName"  ></input>
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.id}" name="companyId"  ></input>
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.id}" name="advertId" ></input>                               
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<form action="DoMakeApplication" method="post" onsubmit="alert('you submitted the form');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

**HTML**

```
<form action="DoMakeApplication" method="post" id="my-form">

    <td>
        <input class="btn type7 color1" type="submit" id="makeApplication" value="Başvur">
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.companyName}" name="companyName"  ></input>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.id}" name="companyId"  ></input>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.id}" name="advertId" ></input>                               
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('my-form').onsubmit = function () {
    alert(42);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/7hLnU/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#makeApplication").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert("alert here"); 
 // use either of the following
 //$(this.form).submit();
 //$(this).parents('form:first').submit();
 //$("form-id").submit(); // best one
});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it like Minko said or you can attach event directly on your button.

In a javascript file write:

```
$( "#buttonId" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Hello, i'm an alert" );
});
```

THen remember to add your javascript file to your project

Answer (score 0):

Alok is correct in case you want to give an id to your form you can do it like this:

```
$( "#yourFormId" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert( "some alert message" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using java script.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function myalert(){
            alert("Form is submitted");
        }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td colspan="" rowspan="" headers=""><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="enter username"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td colspan="" rowspan="" headers=""><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="enter password"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="1" rowspan="" headers="" align="right"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" onclick="myalert()" placeholder=""></td>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="" headers="" align="right"><a href="signup.html">Click to signup</a></td>

        </tr>

        </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```